# How to use LoginView control with Membership API Roles

Tags: asp.net, .net, membership, loginview

I want to use the roles based authorization in my web site.
I have created one role named 'Admin' in the database using default asp.net configuration (in website menu in visual studio).
I am using default membership API database. (Created using  aspnet_regsql.exe tool).

So I want to use the same roles from the database for LoginView control.

Following is the LoginView Control which I have created.

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
        <LoggedInTemplate>
        <h2>This is the logged in template</h2>
        </LoggedInTemplate>
        <AnonymousTemplate>
        <h2>You are not authenticated</h2>
        </AnonymousTemplate>
        <RoleGroups>
            <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Admin">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkBtnCreateUser" 
                        onclick="lnkBtnCreateUser_Click">
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:RoleGroup>
        </RoleGroups>
        </asp:LoginView>
```

But this control do not display anything for any type of the above mentioned users.
Can anybody explain me the exact lacking thing to be implemented in my above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find a quick explanation video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yj1Iu2RaEdE

Cheers

Comment: It is a good video. I have done exactly the same.But it's not working:-(

Comment: Than probably the problem is somewhere else, and not in use of LoginView.